# Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

How to enable multiple streaming SQL queries to be run on Kafka stream from a single job. Is the structured streaming is a reliable way of going ahead. For example, I'm running 10 queries on a stream in a single job. Suppose I want to run only 9 queries is there a way to dynamically change the queries to be run from a store for every run. I want the queries to be run to dynamically picked from a store for every run of the execute of the Streaming query aka Continuous query.

Comment: I don't get your requirement. But you can get the query objects and start or stop any of them when using structured streaming.

Comment: Hi zsxwing, In the following example the https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/JavaStructuredKafkaWordCount.java

Comment: Hi zsxwing, In the following example the https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/JavaStructuredKafkaWordCount.java The query object execution is blocked until it is terminated. However is it possible to access this object through another object. I want to develop a rest like trigger to change the query been run

Comment: You don't need to call `awaitTermination`. This example needs to block at the end of the main method, otherwise the JVM will exit and the user won't see the outputs.

Comment: I'm planning to use Structured Streaming http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html 

In upcoming releases whether this feature will production ready. If yes I wanted to specify "raw SQL" on the DataSets. 

Could I use the raw SQL on temporary table registered for streaming queries. Is it performant or right way to do.

My functionality is to provide a continuous SQL query over a Kafka Stream.

Comment: You can use raw sql to query the memory sink. The table name is just the query name. However, as the memory sink stores all data in the memory, you should not generate too much data.

Comment: I have similar requirements to leverage existing raw SQL strings, our many  ETL SQLs are too complicated to translated into dataframe API calls, they are either dealing with accumulated data or delta data in a window. Using memory sink seems a good idea, but how should we trigger the SQL execution as soon as the memory sink output is finished? is there some kind of query completion listener that we can put code in?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process multiples queries you should use `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()`

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate() 
val query1 =  spark ... 
val query2 =  spark ...  
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Then, you can read a SQL raw query from a Stream and use its value into a other stream without any problems.